# Когда использовать rem, vh, wh, em?

Tags: css

Расскажите пожалуйста, когда нужно в css использовать размеры в rem, vh, wh, em?

Ещё такой вопрос, 27px = 2.7rem?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `Ещё такой вопрос, 27px = 2.7rem?`, все зависит от того, какой `font-size` стоит у `html`.

Comment: Вообще @OliverPatterson прав, всё зависит от того какой размер шрифта у рут элемента, но если допустим это веб страница **без стилей**, то тогда по дефолту `1rem` (Как и `1em`) = `16px`, то есть `2.7rem = 43.2px = 2.7 * 16`

Comment: а он зависит именно от размера шрифта в определенном блоки?

Comment: `rem` берет размеры `font-size` у `html`, `em` берет у родительского блока.